# What happens in system.out.print with empty quotations marks and no String assignment?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm currently reading "Head First Java". the code is below is one of the exercises. The idea is to figure out the possible output.

There's one thing I don't understand however.

Within the `System.out.print` a couple of empty quotations are used but I thought quotations are only used for `Strings` and in the code example below there is no `Strings`? What is it doing here, how should I read it?

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while ( x < 5 ) {
            y = x - y;
            System.out.println(x + "" + y + " " );
            x = x + 1; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `""` is an empty string.

Comment: Maybe it's to explain the string concatenation ? if you System.out.println(x + "" + y) with x = 5 and y = 6, the result will be "56" and no 11

Comment: In general you could use statements like `x + "" + y` to prevent a **numerical addition**, you want to force a **string concatenation**. This is because `x + ""` wil transform `x` into a `String`, after that the `+` operator means *string concatenation*. However in the current form the `+ ""` at the end of `x + " " + y + ""` is unnecessary as the result already is a `String` before.

Comment: You got the example the wrong way around. The way you had it, there isn't a reason to do it. The way that is **is now**, is for the reasons @Zabuza suggested. The empty string `""` is to concatenate, rather than add, the numbers and the space `" "` is to delimit the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`""` means empty string and `" "` means one space that's it. Don't make it too complex. Try to understand the concept.

And if in your `System.out.println` we did something like this

```
(x + "" + y + " ")
```

What will happen here is:

```
<value of x> + <string which is empty in our case> + <value of y> + <' '>
```

This all will be converted to string